# The burner on my Lennox G40uh furnace will not ignite

Tags: electrical, hvac, furnace, gas, gas-burner

I have a Lennox G40 series furnace and the gas valve will not open.  After it does the preliminary start up I get 27V to the gas valve, but only for about half a second. 
Periodically the LEDs will state that there is open primary/ secondary limits,  but if I jumper those out the problem persists. And by periodically I mean 1 out of 5 times trying to start the furnace from power off to running. The LEDs typically just synchronized fast flash saying there is a call for heat. 
Does it make sense for the limit switch to be the problem?

Comment: If you take the thermostat off its base and jumper R to W, does the problem persist?

Comment: I took the thermostat wires off of the control board in the furnace and jumped R to W. Problem persists.

Comment: Sounds like busted control board.